# Using for each loop in java to print class members, whose instances are stored in a LinkedList of type Class

Tags: java, foreach, collections

There's a class called Student that contains member variables `Id`, `fname` and `lname`. I want to iterate through the objects stored in the Linked List and print their values given through the constructor while adding them int he list.

```
class Coll{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        
        List<Student> stud = new LinkedList<Student>();
        
        stud.add(new Student(101, "Sid", "Kulk"));
        stud.add(new Student(102, "avin", "uti"));
        stud.add(new Student(103, "jack", "tak"));
        stud.add(new Student(104, "Tim", "Dou"));
        
        System.out.println("Student ID\tFname\tLname");
        for(Student s:stud){
            System.out.println(s.getId()+"\t"+s.getFname+"\t"+s.getLname);
        }
    }
}
```

The student class:

```
class Student{
    private int Id;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    
    Student(int id, String fname, String lname){
        Id = id;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    
    void setId(int id){
        this.Id = id;
    }
    
    void setFname(String fname){
        this.fname = fname;
    }
    
    void setLname(String lname){
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    
    int getId(){
        return Id;
    }
    
    String getFname(){
        return fname;
    }
    
    String getLname(){
        return lname;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the question and/or error messages you got.

Comment: I think he did. He wants to print their values given through the constructor while adding them in the list

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to add the round brackets after `getFname` and `getLname` methods when you print the values to the console. It should be like this:

```
System.out.println(s.getId()+"\t"+s.getFname()+"\t"+s.getLname());
```

Comment: Thanks! My bad..   :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it is like "you want to print the content of the list every time you make a call **stud.add(new Student(..));** ,

then you need a custom wrapper around linked list.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your answer correctly. You want to print new students when you add to the list right?

Then You can basically do this

```
Student(int id, String fname, String lname){
    Id = id;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    System.out.println(this.getId()+"\t"+this.getFname() +"\t"+ this.getLname());
}
```

because You create Student class exactly when you adding to the list.

Comment: I actually don't want to print the contents after every time i call the constructor, thanks anyways.